# Python Apache Beam: write results with given file names

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a custom function that gets input from files, and I want to write the function results to files corresponding to source files.

The code is like:

- the custom function:

```
def func(_file):
    result = ...
    return (_file.metadata.path, result)
```

- the pipeline:

```
pcoll_of_file_pattern
| "Search files" >> MatchAll()
| "Read files" >> ReadMatches()
| 'Apply function to files' >> beam.Map(func)
| beam.Map( ??? )
```

The names of source files are needed to create result files, but `WriteToText` do not accepts the output of `func` (source_file_name, function results).

Say I have files `test-1.txt, test-2.txt, ... text-10.txt`, the search pattern would be `test-*.txt`. What I want is saving the results like `result-test-1.txt, result-test-2.txt, ...result-test-10.txt`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you want, but this may be helpful as an example

```
    from apache_beam.io import filesystems


    def fake_processing(element):
        now_str = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return (element, now_str)

    class WriteToSeparateFiles(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            path = element[0]
            writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create(f'Output/{path}.txt')
            writer.write(bytes(element[1], 'utf-8'))
            writer.close()

    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        (p | "Create" >> beam.Create(['file1', 'file2'])
            | beam.Map(fake_processing)
            | "WriteToFileDynamic" >> beam.ParDo(WriteToSeparateFiles()))
```

Comment: above logic always overwriting existing file. any other logic to append if file is exist.